# R - Error while counting nodes in a binary tree: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'

Tags: r, count, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I have a binary tree with structure is as follows:

```
> tree
$is_leaf
[1] FALSE
$prediction
[1] ""
$splitting_feature
[1] "term= 36 months"
$left
$left$splitting_feature
[1] ""
$left$left
[1] ""
$left$right
[1] ""
$left$is_leaf
[1] TRUE
$left$prediction
[1] -1
$right
$right$splitting_feature
[1] ""
$right$left
[1] ""
$right$right
[1] ""
$right$is_leaf
[1] TRUE
$right$prediction
[1] 1
```

I have written the following recursive function to count the number of nodes in a binary search tree.

```
count_nodes<-function(tree){

        if(tree['is_leaf']==TRUE)
        {return(1)} else{

                return(1+count_nodes(tree['left']) + count_nodes(tree['right']))    
                }

}
```

When I call this function as

```
> count_nodes(tree)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in count_nodes(tree["left"]) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

`dput(tree)` is as follows:

```
> dput(tree)
structure(list(is_leaf = FALSE, left = structure(list(is_leaf = TRUE, 
    left = "", right = ""), .Names = c("is_leaf", "left", "right"
)), right = structure(list(is_leaf = TRUE, left = "", right = ""), .Names = c("is_leaf", 
"left", "right"))), .Names = c("is_leaf", "left", "right"))
>
```

Please help out in solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please `dput` on your `tree` object and add it in question. It will help people to answer.

Comment: @MKR Thanks for your suggestion. I have added output of dput(tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you subset a list using single brackets, you will get a sublist. To extract an element of a list, use double brackets.

Here is the error that occurs when using single brackets:

```
tree <- list(
  is_leaf = F,
  left = list(is_leaf = T, left = "", right = ""),
  right = list(is_leaf = T, left = "", right = ""))

count_nodes <- function(tree){
  if(tree['is_leaf'] == TRUE) {
    return(1)
  } else{
    return(1 + count_nodes(tree['left']) + count_nodes(tree['right']))    
  }
}

count_nodes(tree)
#> Error in count_nodes(tree["left"]): (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

Using double brackets fixes the issue.

```
count_nodes <- function(tree){
  if(tree[['is_leaf']]) {
    return(1)
  } else{
    return(1 + count_nodes(tree[['left']]) + count_nodes(tree[['right']]))    
  }
}

count_nodes(tree)
#> [1] 3
```